# How to draw Cubic bezier curve in react application using d3.js

Tags: reactjs, bezier, curve, cubic

I am trying to draw a cubic bezier curve in my React application which can be dragged up and down from a control point which is near the apex of the curve and from the end point of the curve. I have drawn the svg curve but unable to manipulate it’s shape. Could anybody guide me any library or plug in for this or share me an example similar to this?

Comment: I think this link would be helpful which gives you how to draw a cubic bezier and how to set its values https://easings.net/en

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please be aware that you've asked the kind of question that this site is explicitly [not for](/help/on-topic), so please remember to take the [tour], and if possible please edit your question to not ask for recommendations, but instead show some (ideally [mcve]) code to explain what you're already trying, and keeping the post in line with the ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article.

Comment: If you figure out some day please reply to this comment on how to do it :)